# Check if a div does NOT exist with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Checking if a div exists is fairly simple

```
if(document.getif(document.getElementById('if')){

}
```

But how can I check if a div with the given id does not exist?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
var myElem = document.getElementById('myElementId');
if (myElem === null) alert('does not exist!');
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap modal windows, for some reason JQuery couldn't find elements in the modal window. Vanilla JS worked fine.

Answer (score 81):

```
if (!document.getElementById("given-id")) {
//It does not exist
}
```

The statement `document.getElementById("given-id")` returns `null` if an element with `given-id` doesn't exist, and `null` is falsy meaning that it translates to false when evaluated in an if-statement. ([other falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy))

Comment: Hi Esailija, I reckon you could be the best answer if you added detail to why "!" works well. Perhaps saying that it returns null, which is falsy. +1 from me.

Comment: @CommandZ: Why force people to Google it, when a simple inline explanation would be faster. Besides, I believe what Alex is getting at is that `null` evaluates to `false`, which isn't common knowledge (C# is a language where `null` does not equal false).

Comment: @DougS `null` does not equal to `false` even in coercive equality comparison  - the call to `ToBoolean(null)` returns `false`

Answer (score 13):

Check both my JavaScript and JQuery code :

JavaScript:

```
if (!document.getElementById('MyElementId')){
    alert('Does not exist!');
}
```

JQuery:

```
if (!$("#MyElementId").length){
    alert('Does not exist!');
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try getting the element with the ID and check if the return value is null:

```
document.getElementById('some_nonexistent_id') === null
```

If you're using jQuery, you can do:

```
$('#some_nonexistent_id').length === 0
```

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just do `!document.getElementById('foo')`?

Comment: @ElatedOwl It can happen that you can perform operation on many inputs, and you want to check if they exists. It would be pointless to `document.getElementById()` then.

Answer (score 4):

`getElementById` returns `null` if there is no such element.

Answer (score 3):

There's an even better solution. You don't even need to check if the element returns `null`. You can simply do this:

```
if (document.getElementById('elementId')) {
  console.log('exists')
}
```

That code will only log `exists` to console if the element actually exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

That works with :

```
 var element = document.getElementById('myElem');
 if (typeof (element) != undefined && typeof (element) != null && typeof (element) != 'undefined') {
     console.log('element exists');
 }
 else{
     console.log('element NOT exists');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

All these answers do **NOT** take into account that you asked specifically about a **DIV** element.

```
document.querySelector("div#the-div-id")
```

@see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

I do below and check if `id` exist and execute function if exist.

```
var divIDVar = $('#divID').length;
if (divIDVar === 0){ 
    console.log('No DIV Exist'); 
} else{  
    FNCsomefunction(); 
}
```