# Console blocking execution because getElementbyId is null (but I want it to be)

Tags: javascript

EDIT: The answers of Mr. Veron, Mr. Spungin, and Mr. Shah fit my needs perfectly. My error is apparent, and the console's warning perfectly sensible. Thank you all.

I'm trying to determine the existence of an element in the DOM. [In accordance with what  extant posts have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886190/check-if-a-div-does-not-exist-with-javascript), I've resorted to using getElementbyId + querySelector and then checking if it's null/undefined with a conditional.

```
let target = document.getElementbyId(a).querySelector(b)

if(typeof(target) != 'undefined' && target != null){
...
}
```

Here's where I run into an error. When the first line executes, my console tosses up the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

because "target" is null -- but I *intend* for it to be null, and thus am mildly irked that the console is for once acting against my interest.

This is an [implementation offered and endorsed by many on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom) -- and yet I cannot easily find people facing the same obstruction that I am. Therefore, I'd appreciate any explanations for why such a warning is needed or ways to circumvent it (a better implementation than what has been widely suggested ). Much thanks.

Comment: Using `querySelector` will trigger this error if `getElementById` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Because you are trying to use `querySelector` on the element that might be `null` or `undefined`.

Go with this approach:

```
let element = document.getElementbyId(a);
let target = element && element.querySelector(b);

if(typeof(target) != 'undefined' && target != null){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check for undefined before calling querySelector

```
let target = document.getElementbyId(a) ? document.getElementbyId(a).querySelector(b) : undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, when `.getElementbyId` fails, it's `undefined`, and attempting to call methods on `undefined` raises an error.

This is what the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) operator is for.

You can also simplify your conditional to be `target != undefined`, since both of these methods will return `undefined`, and  `variable != undefined` returns true for `undefined` and `null`.

```js
let target = document.getElementbyId(a)?.querySelector(b);
                               // here ^
if(target != undefined){
...
}
```